# Use for loop to take steps of 15 and match vector to dataframe column

Tags: r, for-loop, match, seq

I have a series of numbers that are 0 or 1. total length is 35115 or if you take 35115/15 you have 2341 blocks. I want to step through each block and see if my vector tmp matches the column of interest that contains the blocks. I want to seq along my dataframe, but take steps of 15 and ask does these 15 match my vector. 
What am I doing wrong? can someone help me? Thank you all for teaching me something useful. Cheers

```
x;
        V1       V2 V3 V4  V5 V6 V7
 3R 11024348  A  G  A1  0 61
 3R 11024348  A  G  A2  1 30
 3R 11024348  A  G  A3  0 68
 3R 11024348  A  G  A4  0 57
 3R 11024348  A  G  A5  0 63
 3R 11024348  A  G  A6  0 49
 3R 11024348  A  G  A7  0 60
 3R 11024348  A  G  B1  0 63
 3R 11024348  A  G  B2  0 64
 3R 11024348  A  G  B3  0 71
 3R 11024348  A  G  B4  1 51
 3R 11024348  A  G  B5  0 37
 3R 11024348  A  G  B6  0 52
 3R 11024348  A  G  B7  0 47
 3R 11024348  A  G AB8  0 83
 3R 11024410  C  T  A1  0 45
 3R 11024410  C  T  A2  1 54
 3R 11024410  C  T  A3  0 76
 3R 11024410  C  T  A4  0 48
 3R 11024410  C  T  A5  0 49
 3R 11024410  C  T  A6  1 48
 3R 11024410  C  T  A7  0 45
 3R 11024410  C  T  B1  0 48
 3R 11024410  C  T  B2  0 81
 3R 11024410  C  T  B3  1 58
 3R 11024410  C  T  B4  1 50
 3R 11024410  C  T  B5  0 65
 3R 11024410  C  T  B6  1 45
 3R 11024410  C  T  B7  0 66
 3R 11024410  C  T AB8  0 58


tmp<-c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
for(i in seq(from=1, to=length(X$V6), by=15)){print(matchID<-match(tmp,X$V6[i]))}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Roland any data would have worked, but here is a small slice of the real data. I want to match x$V6 to tmp in steps of 15. Here would be two steps.

Comment: Why is this getting negative votes? I provide a specific problem with specific needs and an example of a loop that I cant get to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a `for loop`, you need to define a datastructure in order to store your loop results (could be a vector of numbers, strings, list, matrix, etc).

something like `matchID<-vector()`

let's look at your code:

```
for(i in seq(from=1, to=length(X$V6), by=15)){print(matchID<-match(tmp,X$V6[i]))}
```

your for function calls a loop from 1 to 30 (length of V6) jump by 15 (length of tmp), so it is going to return:

```
>for(i in seq(1,30,15)) print(i)
[1] 1
[1] 16
```

so if you index your V6 vector by i, the loop will only return the value at 1 and 16.

Here is my solution:

```
matchID<-vector() # stores the loop return in a vector
for(i in 1:length(x[, "V6"]){  
  matchID[i]<- as.numeric(tmp == x[, "V6"])[i]
}
```

you can see that for *i*th element in matchID, it always equals to the *i*th element in the vector comparing temp and "V6".

However, you really don't need a loop in this case

```
matchID<-as.numeric(tmp == x[, "V6"])
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, this was a huge help. I had a thought process on how to do this, and got 3 answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure regarding the expected output, but maybe this:

First reproduce the data:

```
x <- read.table(text = "        V1       V2 V3 V4  V5 V6 V7
 3R 11024348  A  G  A1  0 61
                3R 11024348  A  G  A2  1 30
                3R 11024348  A  G  A3  0 68
                3R 11024348  A  G  A4  0 57
                3R 11024348  A  G  A5  0 63
                3R 11024348  A  G  A6  0 49
                3R 11024348  A  G  A7  0 60
                3R 11024348  A  G  B1  0 63
                3R 11024348  A  G  B2  0 64
                3R 11024348  A  G  B3  0 71
                3R 11024348  A  G  B4  1 51
                3R 11024348  A  G  B5  0 37
                3R 11024348  A  G  B6  0 52
                3R 11024348  A  G  B7  0 47
                3R 11024348  A  G AB8  0 83
                3R 11024410  C  T  A1  0 45
                3R 11024410  C  T  A2  1 54
                3R 11024410  C  T  A3  0 76
                3R 11024410  C  T  A4  0 48
                3R 11024410  C  T  A5  0 49
                3R 11024410  C  T  A6  1 48
                3R 11024410  C  T  A7  0 45
                3R 11024410  C  T  B1  0 48
                3R 11024410  C  T  B2  0 81
                3R 11024410  C  T  B3  1 58
                3R 11024410  C  T  B4  1 50
                3R 11024410  C  T  B5  0 65
                3R 11024410  C  T  B6  1 45
                3R 11024410  C  T  B7  0 66
                3R 11024410  C  T AB8  0 58", header = TRUE)

tmp<-c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
```

Now use integer division to define the blocks and then use `aggregate` or the "split-apply-combine" function of your choice:

```
aggregate(x$V6, list(block = (seq_len(nrow(x)) - 1) %/% 15), FUN = function(v) all(v == tmp))
#  block     x
#1     0 FALSE
#2     1 FALSE
```

A probably faster alternative would be to transform the column of your data.frame into a matrix and do this:

```
colSums(matrix(x$V6, nrow = 15) == tmp) == 15L
#[1] FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Hi Roland, this is a great way of doing what I am asking that I didnt even consider. What about a forloop? I ask, because it bothers me I couldnt figure of the forloop.

Comment: I don't understand what you do there with `print` and `match`, but the basic idea is that you need to calculate the indices, i.e., `i + 0:14`.

Comment: Hi roland, I am not use to the aggregate function very much. If you do find a match is there an easy way to reverse course and pull out match in the dataframe?